# Generic method with type argument not found by Java compiler

Tags: java, generics

I have spent most of a day trying to understand why Java cannot compile a simple generic method with a generic type argument, but only when the enclosing class is imported. Basically, I am exposing a Spring context operation as a static method in a class called SpringApplicationContext:

```
public static <T> List<T> listBeansOfType(Class<T> type)
{
  return new ArrayList<T>(context.getBeansOfType(type).values());
}
```

When I call it from a unit test in the same package, it works. Here's the test call:

```
 List<DomainRepo> repos =
   SpringApplicationContext.listBeansOfType(DomainRepo.class);
```

However, the exact same code fails when I call it from code in another package. The compiler says it cannot find the symbol listBeansOfType(java.lang.Class). I have imported the class, but I have not done a static import on the method.

Even stranger is the fact that this code worked a week ago when I wrote it. Since then, I had to put it all aside while working through a release process. The same error occurs when I compile with maven or Eclipse, using java 1.6. Any hints will be more than welcome.

Comment: Is this class it is in public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have all needed maven dependencies. If your Junit Test works, but mvn compile fails the dependency could be included with scope Test.

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>group-a</groupId>
       <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>TEST</scope> <!-- would explain why you can run your code as junit -->
    </dependency>
```

Check the type of "context" and where the method getBeansOfType() is defined. They might be missing as mvn dependency.

Comment: Thanks a million - it was indeed an incorrect dependency, but nothing as simple as this. Your comment prompted me to dig through the dependency tree, and there was one that had not been updated from release version to master development version.

Comment: Um - actually, I spoke too soon. There was an out-of-date dependency that would have brought in an older version of SpringApplicationContext, without the method in question. However, fixing that dependency did not change the symptom at all.

Comment: I think I have been a victim of some sort of bad caching behavior in Eclipse - after removing the module containing the `listBeansOfType()` method from ~/.m2/repository (I had installed and removed it previously), and rebuilding and updating Maven dependencies several times in Eclipse, it finally decided to play nice. No other changes...

Comment: It sounded like a dependency problem. If you have the possibility to update to Eclipse Indigo RC1 and newest Maven plugin you should really consider it. Some nasty bugs were fixed, and Eclipse will also provide "force update", which will clear your repository and refetch the modules! For me the upgrade fixed some major issues between WTP and Maven.